# Is there a way arround rosdep inititialize?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just did a fill did a full install of ros indigo on my ubuntu 14.04(as per the ros tutorial). When i try to initialize rosdep it says..

```
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.
```

What is the solution for this? Or did i do something wrong, in which case what should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263604/is-there-a-way-arround-rosdep-inititialize?/) by [Shubhayu Das](https://answers.ros.org/users/28390/shubhayu-das/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check your networking for proxies or other issues.

If you need to you can manually copy the files into the correct location.

```
root@0c988f5d8e4c:/# cat /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list 
# os-specific listings first
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml osx

# generic
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/base.yaml
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
gbpdistro https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml fuerte

# newer distributions (Groovy, Hydro, ...) must not be listed anymore, they are being fetched from the rosdistro index.yaml instead
```

You will also get this error if your ssl certificates are unavailable.

```
root@0c988f5d8e4c:/# apt remove ca-certificates 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  file libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libffi6 libmagic1 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 mime-support openssl python python-all python-all-dev python-dev
  python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-wheel python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ca-certificates python-pip python-pip-whl
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2351 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 16375 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-pip (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Removing python-pip-whl (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Removing ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Removing dangling symlinks from /etc/ssl/certs... done.
root@0c988f5d8e4c:/# rosdep init
ERROR: cannot download default sources list from:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
Website may be down.
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1